# Sign aware loss function

Tags: loss-functions

I want to create a regression model with the following properties:

- prediction should be close to target
- target and prediction should have the same sign
- small penalty if either target or prediction are close to 0
- extra penalty if both are far from zero and have opposite sign

Consider the following loss function: $$\mathcal L _\alpha (y, \hat y) = (y - \hat y)^2 - \alpha y\hat y, $$
where $\alpha \geq 0$ parameter.

Questions:

- Is it a valid loss function?
- Does it fulfills the requirements?
- Can it be improved?
- Are there any issues with such loss?
- Have someone tried something similar?

Comment: The standard quadratic loss satisfies all your criteria.

Comment: @whuber I think OP's (4) means that, for $x_1,\hat x_1$ and $x_2,\hat x_2$ such that $|x_1-\hat x_1| = |x_2-\hat x_2|$ but, say $x_1,\hat x_1 > 0$ while $x_2 < 0, \hat x_2 > 0$, that we should have $\mathcal{L}(x_1,\hat x_1) < \mathcal{L}(x_2,\hat x_2)$, which is not satisfied by quadratic loss (or any other translation invariant loss).

Comment: dear OP, you could try something like $(y_i-\hat y_i)^2 + \alpha \max(0, -\mathrm{sgn}(y_i) \hat y_i) $, which is convex.

Comment: What is your definition of a loss function for your first bullet point?

Comment: @JohnMadden thanks a lot for suggestion! Can it be $(y_i - \hat y_i)^2 + \alpha \max (0, -y_i \hat y_i)$ to take into account that for small $y_i$ extra penalty should be small regardless of prediction?

Comment: (3) is strange because the algorithm can't control the target. And it conflicts with (1): if the target is, say, 0.001, then what do you want the optimal prediction to be?

Comment: Maybe you can add a logloss between 1(y>0) and 1(y_hat>0).

Comment: @lcrmorin How would that work for values that aren’t bounded to $(0, 1)?$

Comment: Consider a mixture model with a sign (i.e. asymmetric Rademacher/ shifted Bernoulli) and magnitude component. It's often the case that it is possible to maximize the likelihood of such a parametric model. You can use its negative loglikelihood as a loss function.

Comment: Please post your question about the new loss function as its own question. It deserves a set of answers distinct from those about your first function.

Comment: @Firebug can you please post some links to read about asymmetric Rademacher/ shifted Bernoulli please?

Comment: @John My point is that the criteria are too vague and permit too many different responses.  The question needs clarification.

Comment: i was working on this problem in the context of optical flow estimation, I think that the following paper and supplementary material could be of good help! https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/WACV2023/html/Savian_Towards_Equivariant_Optical_Flow_Estimation_With_Deep_Learning_WACV_2023_paper.html Regards,
Stefano

Answer (score 7):

I have to admit that I disagree with [Dave's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/621061/1352) (but I did upvote it, because it is useful). In my opinion, it makes little sense to consider your loss as a function of *two* variables when we optimize. After all, we usually cannot influence the true outcome $y$ or its distribution, only our point prediction $\hat{y}$.

Thus, I submit that it is more helpful to think about this as considering your loss as a random variable (through the uncertainty in the outcome $y$) which depends on a variable $\hat{y}$, and trying to understand which value of $\hat{y}$ minimizes, e.g., the expectation of your loss.

I like to investigate things like this through simple simulations. For example, in analogy to your other thread ([Loss function that penalizes wrong sign predictions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/621102/1352)), assume your predictive uncertainty about the outcome can be parameterized as a normal distribution with mean 1 and standard deviation 2. It turns out that the $\hat{y}$ that minimizes the expected loss for $\alpha=1$ is 1.5, i.e., your loss incentivizes us to give a prediction that is higher than the mean. This may well be what you want - but it is important to be aware of this effect.

[image: loss function]

R code:

```
mm <- 1
sd <- 2
xx <- mm+seq(-2*sd,2*sd,by=0.01)

sims <- rnorm(1e6,mm,sd)
alpha <- 1
loss <- sapply(xx,function(yy)mean((sims-yy)^2-alpha*sims*yy))
xx[which.min(loss)]

plot(xx,loss,type="l",xlab="Point prediction",las=1,ylab="Expected loss")
abline(v=mm,col="red")
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that it will tend to predict higher (in absolute values) predictions rather than true value. Although, I take that since for the same sign I don't really care about how large deviation is. I proposed another idea in parallel topic [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621102/loss-function-that-penalizes-wrong-sign-predictions) which you have already answered.