# Modification of square loss analogous to absolute and vs pinball loss: what is elicited?

Tags: regression, loss-functions, quantile-regression

Quantile regression at quantile $\tau$ minimizes the following ["pinball"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/471224/pinball-loss-as-a-synonym-for-quantile-loss-misleading) loss function, $L_{\tau}$, and [elicits](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/621105/247274) conditional quantile $\tau$.

$$
l_{\tau}(y_i, \hat y_i) = \begin{cases}
      \tau\vert y_i - \hat y_i\vert, & y_i - \hat y_i \ge 0 \\
      (1 - \tau)\vert y_i - \hat y_i\vert, & y_i - \hat y_i < 0
   \end{cases}\\
L_{\tau}(y, \hat y) = \sum_{i=1}^n l_{\tau}(y_i, \hat y_i)
$$

When $\tau = 0.5$, this loss function is absolute loss.

If we generalize squared loss the way that absolute loss generalizes to the pinball loss, denotes as $L^{^*}_{\tau}$ below, what is elicited?

$$
l^{^*}_{\tau}(y_i, \hat y_i) = \begin{cases}
      \tau\left( y_i - \hat y_i\right)^2, & y_i - \hat y_i \ge 0 \\
      (1 - \tau)\left( y_i - \hat y_i\right)^2, & y_i - \hat y_i < 0
   \end{cases}\\
L^{^*}_{\tau}(y, \hat y) = \sum_{i=1}^n l^{^*}_{\tau}(y_i, \hat y_i)
$$

When $\tau = 0.5$, this is just the usual squared loss that elicits conditional means. When $\tau\ne 0.5$, I am not sure what such a loss function would elicit.

Comment: I’ve heard of something called an *expectile* whose definition hasn’t quite made sense to me. Perhaps this is an equivalent definition, one that is easier for me to interpret.

Comment: You are correct, the (conditional) expectile is elicited. Are you asking for a definition?

Comment: @picky_porpoise A way to tie this to the "tail expectation" would be appreciated.